# Java GUI changing colour of theme

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

[image: How?]

How do I change the normal default theme to something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `Look and Feel` of your application, you can design your own L&F or used an already existing one such as [`Nimbus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)

You can implement Nimbus like so:

```
try {
    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("If Nimbus is not available, fall back to cross-platform");
    e.printStackTrace();
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the look and feel. Google is your friend, but here is the official Look and Feel tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html

Note that you can set the L&F programatically, or you can set it via a command line argument.